# ASP.NET asynchronous controllers and long polling

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, comet, long-polling, reverse-ajax

I've been looking for IIS based solutions for comet/push/reverse-ajax pages, and came upon [asynchronous controllers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx#Y945)

It seems like that allows xhr long polling without the problem of running out of threads, am I correct? Does this allow fairly decent scaling for long polling pages?

Comment: Scalability is a quite a complex concept. You cannot say it is scalable while you don't build it and test it.

Comment: Develop a project, carry out a stress test, then optimize, then stress test, then optimize, then stress test...

Comment: There are inherent scalability problems that can be solved before testing / optimization. I know that with a plain long poll request, each client using a page will use a thread, and that puts a low cap on the number of clients that can be connected. Asynchronous controllers will theoretically get rid of that particular constraint - however I see a lot of questions on here about IIS / ASP comet implementations, and no one has suggested using async controllers as a solution (that I've seen), which makes me wonder if there is something I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say take a look at [signalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR).  [Nodejs](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx) for iis is also an option

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a pro solution with built in websocket, pick [PokeIn](http://pokein.com)

Answer (score 0):

See [ASP.NET MVC 3 real time events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055651/asp-net-mvc-3-real-time-events/9069890).

To make scaling easier/less of an issue I'd recommend using a dedicated realtime server (see this [realtime technology guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide); something that has been built from the ground up with realtime communication in mind.